# how to capture double quotes in a ASP.NET page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, string

I have a text box on my web page which I want to allow the user to type double quotes in.

It's a web report kind of deal.

So users can enter in

```
breaking
```

or

`"breaking"` if they want to capture the exact word.

The issue is, when I look at the variable when I try to do `"breaking"`, I keep getting this:

```
"\"breaking bad\""
```

I need to get `"breaking bad"` ...

How do I go about doing this properly? Is there NOT a way to do this and therefore I have to simply do a replace?

Comment: When you're looking at the variable are you doing it via the debugger? If so, the debugger escapes the string automatically as that's how it requires the string internally. The actual variable will hold just `"breaking"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backslashes that you are seeing are just Visual Studio's way of displaying quotes inside a string when using the debugger to inspect a variable.  You are getting the correct value.  If you use the 'Text Visualizer' feature in the debugger to examine the string, you'll see that the backslashes aren't really there.

Comment: You mean that's how the debugger displays them.

Comment: The problem is that this I'm building a URL to do an API call and when I go under debug mode in the API, I'm not getting a double quotes for the string... I'm getting the slashes. Should I check for the slashes rather than the double quotes? I need to be able to REMOVE the double quotes (or slashes)

Comment: @Rj.: You don't need to check for slashes at all - it's an optical illusion that they seem to be there.   If your string has a quote in it, then the debugger will put a backslash `\` in front of it so you know it's a real quote

Answer (score 2):

> when I look at the variable when I try to do "breaking", I keep getting this:
>
> `"\"breaking bad\""`

If by "looking" you mean in the debugger, then what you are seeing is the debugger escaping the quotes by adding the backslashes.  If you output that string to the console, a form, database, etc.  It will be surrounded by quotes just as you'd expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the debugger displays it. If you want to see the real version quickly, click on the loupe next to the value you're displaying in the debugger.